# I can't solve the logic

Tags: logic

I think for the logic question for a long time. It seems easy but very hard. I don't know how to prove it using equivalence.

(A->(B->C))->((A->(C->D))->(A->(B->D)))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of `A->B` (that is, `~A v B`) and DeMorgan's Law to come up with an equivalent expression in disjunctive normal form (all ands and ors).  From there, repeatedly apply the fact that `A v ~A` is true to simplify the expression to True.  (The latter may require the use of *distribution*: `A v (B ^ C) = (A v B) ^ (A v C)`, as well as `A ^ (B v C) = (A ^ B) v (A ^ C)`, although the former will be of more use here.)

Comment: Thank you so much. But when I come up with (A^B^~C)  V (A^V^~D) V ~A V ~B V D                                                                                   I don't know how to do then with the technology. Could you explain further on this question?